# Getting array([10]) issue

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to ML and learning concepts. I am importing one csv file contained some columns with customer code and product details. I am trying to predict the what product will buy future also but getting array([10])

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import numpy as np
sales_data = pd.read_csv("salesdata.csv")
sales_data = sales_data.astype('int32')
X = sales_data.drop(columns=['Product'])
y = sales_data['Product']
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)
predictions = model.predict([[7301, 52199000]])
predictions
```

Comment: What do you expect to get?

Comment: What is the issue? post expected and actual results.

Answer (score 0):

So the good news is, your code is all great. Just a little misunderstanding on what the model is returning... Basically it is saying product number '10' is its prediction based off of the values you plugged into model.predict(). This is the models way of talking to us, and sometimes we need to take an extra step to see what that tenth class label is in our language. Try `model.classes_` ; this should print all of the class names the model is trained on.